# Submitting form data to controller action

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to POST data from a form to a controller action. I am not sure if I am doing this correctly or how to test if the data is getting sent because I am new to rails at the moment

HTML:

```
      <%= form_tag({controller: "home", action: "send_mail"}, method: "get") %>
        <div class="col-md-12">
          <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="form-group">
              <%= text_field(:name) %>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <%= email_field(:email) %>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <%= telephone_field(:phone) %>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-6">
            <%= text_area_tag(:body, "Message...", size: "24x6") %>
          </div>
          <button id="send-btn" class="btn btn-xl" type="submit">SEND MESSAGE</button>
        </div>
      <% end %>
```

I want the data to be sent to be send to this controller action

```
class HomeController < ApplicationController
  def index
  end

  def send_mail
    name = params[:name]
    email = params[:email]
    phone = params[:phone]
    body = params[:body]
    UserMailer.contact_mail(name, email, body).deliver
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Check your log. In your terminal, from the window in which you started `rails server`, you should see a running log of the activities happening in your app. After you submit the form, you should see something like the following:

`Started POST "/home/send_mail: for 127.0.0.1 at xxxx-xx-xx
Processing by HomeController#send_mail as xxxx
Completed 200 OK in xxms`

This will verify a) the correct route was processed by your server; b) The route was processed by the intended controller action and c) the server code you received. It's probable the correct controller action is handing this route but your mailer isn't configured correctly. Start with the logs. If you need more advanced debugging, check out the invaluable pry (https://github.com/pry/pry).